# Webflux Webclient escape slash in URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I need to include a slash in an URL to access RabbitMQ API and I'm trying to fetch data using `WebClient`:

```
WebClient.builder()
     .baseUrl("https://RABBIT_HOSTNAME/api/queues/%2F/QUEUE_NAME")
     .build()
     .get().exchange();
```

When I replace `/` with `%2F` I can see in the request descriptor that `%2F` has been changed to `%252F` and because of it I'm getting not found response.

I've tried the following options:

• `"\\/"` - WebClient changes to `%5C` but Rabbit doesn't interpret it correctly and returns 404.

• `"%5C"` - WebClient changes to `%255C`, Rabbit returns 404.

How can I persist `%2F` in an url using WebClient?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default it will always encode the URL, so I can see two options

1. Completely ignore the `baseUrl` method and pass a fully qualified URL into the `uri` method which will override the `baseUrl` method.

   ```
   WebClient.builder()
        .build()
        .uri(URI.create( "https://RABBIT_HOSTNAME/api/queues/%2F/QUEUE_NAME"))
        .get().exchange();
   ```
2. Create your own custom UriBuilderFactory, map a Uri, and set the encoding to `NONE`

   ```
   public class CustomUriBuilderFactory extends DefaultUriBuilderFactory {

       public CustomUriBuilderFactory(String baseUriTemplate) {
           super(UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(baseUriTemplate));
           super.setEncodingMode(EncodingMode.NONE);
       }
   }
   ```

   and then you can use `uriBuilderFactory`  of `baseUrl`, which will allow you to still use uri for just the uri part

   ```
   WebClient.builder()
           .uriBuilderFactory(
               new CustomUriBuilderFactory(
                   "https://RABBIT_HOSTNAME/api/queues/%2F/QUEUE_NAME"
           ))
           .build()
           .get()
           .uri(whatever)
           .exchange();
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this:

```
URI uri = URI.create("%2F");
```

And:

```
WebClient.builder()
        .baseUrl("https://RABBIT_HOSTNAME/api/queues")
        .build()
        .post()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.pathSegment(uri.getPath(), "QUEUE_NAME").build())...
```

Comment: I corrected the answer, maybe this solution will work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the uriBuilder and specify a path with a placeholder that is completed via the build method then the argument in the build method is automatically encoded correctly:

```
client.get()
      .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/foo/{fooValue}")
                                   .build(valueWithSpecialCharacter))
      .retrieve()
      .bodyToMono(Foo.class);
```